# Python selenium iframe, #document and again iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I have to get that src on the bottom of the code

```
<html>
 <head>...</head>
 <body class>
  <div class="class1"....</div>
    <div class="class2"....</div>
     <section id=...>
       <div id="id1"...</div>
         <div id="id2"...</div>
           <iframe id="iframe" src= "almost" ...>
             #document
               <html>
                 <head>...</head>
                 <body>
                   <div id=".."</div>
                   <iframe id="iframe" src="thats what I want" /iframe>
```

I can get the first iframe src "almost" with this code:

```
 elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='id2']/iframe").get_attribute('src')
```

Tried to get botton src with code:

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0]
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe").get_attribute('src')
print element
```

but I get only captcha error, that I'm not human, so I think there is something wrong inside #document and iframe

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can write

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[2]").get_attribute('src')
```

to find the second iframe's `src` attribute, though I have never encountered such a situation. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I've never encountered nested iframes, so I expect this is some characteristic specific to them.

Comment: My code in first post is working, it was problem with captcha after many tries :)

Answer (score 0):

My code is working, it was problem with captcha